# How can I set the default date format for Twig templates in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

Twig documentation describes how to set the default date format for the `date` filter:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->getExtension('core')->setDateFormat('d/m/Y', '%d days');
```

How can do this setting globally in Symfony2?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For a more detailed solution.

in your bundle create a Services folder that can contain the event listener

```
namespace MyApp\AppBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class TwigDateRequestListener
{
    protected $twig;

    function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig) {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
        $this->twig->getExtension('core')->setDateFormat('Y-m-d', '%d days');
    }
}
```

Then we will want symfony to find this listener.
In the `Resources/config/services.yml` file put

```
services:
    twigdate.listener.request:
        class: MyApp\AppBundle\Services\TwigDateRequestListener
        arguments: [@twig]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

by specifying @twig as an argument it will be injected into the `TwigDateRequestListener`

Make shure that your importing the services.yml at the top of `app/config.yml`

```
imports:
    - { resource: @MyAppAppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml }
```

Now you should be able to skip the format in the date filter as such

```
{{ myentity.dateAdded|date }}
```

and it should get the formatting from the service.

Comment: Cool, thanks! BTW, unused use statement `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;` ;)

Answer (score 14):

As of Symfony 2.7, you can configure the default date format globally in `config.yml`:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    date:
        format: d.m.Y, H:i:s
        interval_format: '%%d days'
        timezone: Europe/Paris
```

The same is also possible for the `number_format` filter. Details can be found here: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-default-date-and-number-format-configuration

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to distinguish date from datetime objects, and thus it is not possible to set different formats for date and datetime, AFAIK...

Answer (score 2):

In controller you can do

```
$this->get('twig')->getExtension('core')->setDateFormat('d/m/Y', '%d days');
```

Comment: This was my first idea, too. I would prefer a global setting in config.yml or with a listener so that it's valid in the whole project. I just added "globally" to my question to be clear.

Comment: Well it can not be done by adding a config in config.yml AFIK. TwigBundle does not expose core extension. Yes you can add a request listener to accomplish this.

Comment: Setting works fine globally when done in a request listener. I'm injecting the `twig` service of class `\Twig_Environment` and can do the setting as described above.

Comment: Can you supply an example of how to handle a default date format via the config.yml

Answer (score 1):

for Symfony 4 you can do this for those that need.

```
twig:
    ...
    date:
        format: c
        timezone: UTC
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in my Twig installation (frameworkless) no extension named 'core' exists, I had to use **Twig_Extension_Core**

```php
$twig->getExtension('Twig_Extension_Core')->setDateFormat($dateFormat);
```

Tested in Twig version **v2.14.6**

Answer (score -1):

The global Twig configuration options can be found on:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/configuration/twig.html

In my opinion the 'date_format' option should be added here, since making use of the Sonata Intl bundle is overkill for most of the users.