# How do i set the Twig default date and number formats depending on which user is logged in in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, twig

I want my twig dates and numbers (eg. {{ number|numberformat}} )to be in a format that is chosen by my users.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886058/how-can-i-set-the-default-date-format-for-twig-templates-in-symfony2) it was suggested to make a listener to set the default twig formats. I don't fully understand this approach, so im not sure if this code can be adapted to make sure that dates are shown in a chosen format? (i mean to have a method User::getDateFormat() )
Or would you recommend another approach?

Thanks!

Comment: That answer is fine: you should only inject current user also and, inside listener, retrieve user choice for data format.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that! Could you explain to me at what moment the onKernelRequest is called?

Comment: Take a look to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject user also and all will work like a charm

```
namespace MyApp\AppBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class TwigDateRequestListener
{
    protected $twig;
    protected $context;

    function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, SecurityContext $context) 
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) 
    {
        $user = $this->context->getToken()->getUser();
        $user_date_format = $user->//function to retrieve date settings
        $this->twig->getExtension('core')->setDateFormat('Y-m-d', '%d days');
    }
}
```

And remember to modify service definition

```
services:
    twigdate.listener.request:
        class: MyApp\AppBundle\Services\TwigDateRequestListener
        arguments: [@twig, @security.context]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

`onKernelRequest` is called when `kernel.request` event is raised (take a look to service definition and you'll probably understood this)

`kernel.request` is raised every time a page is raised at every request

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't seem to get even the answer to the original question work though. But i'll figure it out.